# FabricJS SVG to canvas (using FileReader)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

On my page, I have a button and a canvas with the following attributes -

```
<button onclick="openSVG()">Open</button>
<canvas></canvas>
```

On clicking the button, the `openSVG()` function is supposed to

- Let the user select and open an SVG file from their local hard drive (previously created using FabricJS)
- Read the contents of the SVG file using FileReader and storing it in a variable
- Using that variable to populate the canvas using `fabric.loadSVGFromString()` method

Now clicking on Open button opens a file selection window but doesnt draw objects into canvas. Here's my openSVG() function -

```
function openSVG() {

// importing file
var input = $(document.createElement('input'));
input.attr("id", "mySVGFile")
input.attr("type", "file");
input.trigger('click');

//storing file contents in var using FileReader
var myInputFile = document.getElementById('mySVGFile');
var myFile = myInputFile.files[0];

var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(){

    var canvasD = this.result;

    //loading data from var to canvas
    fabric.loadSVGFromString(canvasD, function(objects, options) {
        var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
    });
};

fr.readAsText(myFile); }
```

I'm new to FileReader. There's no errors in console so I can't even tell where I'm going wrong.
Does my approach not work? Is there a better way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a much more easier and better approach using **[`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)** method ...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function openSVG(e) {
   var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
   fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(objects, options) {
      objects.forEach(function(svg) {
         svg.set({
            top: 90,
            left: 90,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
         });
         svg.scaleToWidth(50);
         svg.scaleToHeight(50);
         canvas.add(svg).renderAll();
      });
   });
}
```

```css
canvas{margin-top:5px;border:1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onchange="openSVG(event)">
<canvas id="c" width="180" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it solves half the problem.
Is there any way to draw the objects on canvas which can be individually manipulated?
For example, Suppose the svg contains data about a circle and a rectangle, I want to resize and drag these shapes around separately.

Comment: yes, possible. you'd have to add them separately instead of grouping them. check updated answer.

Comment: When I add the SVG to Canvas, I get the type as path and a path array. Is it possible to get the type (object) as "Circle", "Rect", "Line", etc, depending upon the path rather than path? OR Is it possible to convert to the path to Canvas standard objects like circle, Rect, etc?